# Remove elements from 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array, casting

I want to remove elements that are in `routedClients` from `array`, so I converted it to an `ArrayList`, then used `remove`, finally I converted it back to `double[][]` array. But when I execute it, it gives me this message about this line:

```
double[][] remainingStockout = (double[][]) stockout.toArray();
```

The error is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [[Ljava.lang.Double;

Any help would be really appreciated. :)

```
public double[][] removeSite(double[][] array) {

    List<double[]> stockout = new ArrayList<double[]>(Arrays.asList(array));

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < routedClients.size(); j++) {

            if (array[i][0] == routedClients.get(j)) {

                stockout.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }

    double[][] remainingStockout = (double[][]) stockout.toArray();

    return remainingStockout;

}
```

Comment: The array you used seems to be of primitive type, try below code instead and confirm if it works (use Double instead of double):

    Double[][] remainingStockout = (Double[][]) stockout.toArray();

Comment: It still gives me an exception : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [[Ljava.lang.Double;

Comment: Can you debug and print what is the type returned by stockout.toArray();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below appears to work

```
double[][] remainingStockout = (double[][]) stockout.toArray(new double[][]{});
```

Full class for testing:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    static ArrayList<Double> routedClients = new ArrayList<Double>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[][] arr1 = { { 2, 4, 6 }, { 3, 6, 9 }, { 5, 10, 15 } };
        routedClients.add(new Double(1));
        routedClients.add(new Double(2));
        routedClients.add(new Double(3));

        print(arr1);
        double[][] arr2 = removeSite(arr1);
        print(arr2);
    }

    private static void print(double[][] arr1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
            double[] arr2 = arr1[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
                System.out.println("arr1[" + i + "][" + j + "] = " + arr1[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }


    public static double[][] removeSite(double[][] array) {

        List<double[]> stockout = new ArrayList<double[]>(Arrays.asList(array));
        System.out.println("length before = " + stockout.size());

        for (int i = array.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            for (int j = 0; j < routedClients.size(); j++) {
                if (array[i][0] == routedClients.get(j)) {
                    System.out.println("removing " + routedClients.get(j));
                    stockout.remove(i);
                }
            }
        }
        double[][] remainingStockout = (double[][]) stockout.toArray(new double[][] {});
        System.out.println("length after = " + remainingStockout.length);
        return remainingStockout;
    }

}
```

Here is the output

```
arr1[0][0] = 2.0
arr1[0][1] = 4.0
arr1[0][2] = 6.0
arr1[1][0] = 3.0
arr1[1][1] = 6.0
arr1[1][2] = 9.0
arr1[2][0] = 5.0
arr1[2][1] = 10.0
arr1[2][2] = 15.0
length before = 3
removing 3.0
removing 2.0
length after = 1
arr1[0][0] = 5.0
arr1[0][1] = 10.0
arr1[0][2] = 15.0
```

Comment: It works but the results aren't what I expected, for example I have 2 and 3 in routedClients, it removes 2 but it removes 4 instead of 3. please what can cause this ?

Comment: Go in reverse order in the outer for loop, because when you remove a particular item, the index of the following items is reduced by one. I have corrected the test example in my original post

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to cast an object into an array.

This cannot be done.

Instead you will need to convert each element in the array and then need to add it to they the 2D Array.

The following line will never work:

```
double[][] remainingStockout = (double[][]) stockout.toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast a double array into a list array because the compiler just makes a list with all the elements, but the compiler can't know which size to make a 2D array.

Maybe you could try creating a list of lists. You would need to traverse your array two more times though. One for assigning the values to the nested list and then to assign them again to the double array before returning the value.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the overloaded method of toArray() .. like this -

```
double[][] remainingStockout = new double[array.length][array.length];

    stockout.toArray(remainingStockout);
```